# Bad migration to arduino.se

Tags: discussion, migration

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/203448/revisions has nothing to do with Arduino.  Better off here, or closed.

Comment: Neutral migration.  The EE.SE answer to that question would be "Read datasheet. Write code."  If there is a library in the open source, then the fellow arduinistas might point him to it, because they are more familiar with their own ecosystem.

Comment: OK, it's been closed here (as was the only choice if it remained here).  Happy now?

Comment: The main problem with this was that the OP asked a question that was poorly worded and depended heavily on information that was in a previous question of theirs, without including or linking it. 'Read the datasheet' won't likely help the OP with designing an output tripler and filter for a DDS. Telling them it's too difficult for them might have been useful. Telling them to improve the question.. yes. But it was not about sending simple SPI commands to a DDS.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so, your point is it is a poor question. The way to deal with poor questions is *not* to migrate them to Arduino.SE. It is as poor there as it is here. No need to migrate rubbish.